# Core Data crash my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, core-data

I built my application with the core data. it works very well with an entity that has two attributes.
When I want to add a new entity with a single attribute, my application crashes at launch.

```
2012-07-16 23:11:13.579 myApp[6773:fb03] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x6bb36e0 {metadata=<CFBasicHash 0x6bbae90 [0x1748b48]>{type = immutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x6bbab30 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers"} = <CFArray 0x6bbaf20 [0x1748b48]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
    0 : <CFString 0x1743cd8 [0x1748b48]>{contents = ""}
)}
    4 : <CFString 0x6bbab60 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion"} = <CFNumber 0x6bbaa30 [0x1748b48]>{value = +386, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    6 : <CFString 0x6bbaec0 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashes"} = <CFBasicHash 0x6bbafb0 [0x1748b48]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x6bbaf40 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "AllFamille"} = <CFData 0x6bbaf60 [0x1748b48]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0x5a5b78eb9edf4005bbe8a8d5e85fd102 ... 208bdf48b8b44695}
}

    7 : <CFString 0x1101ad8 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "NSStoreUUID"} = <CFString 0x6bbad30 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "45640157-116E-4616-93C5-2DA6027F4E9C"}
    8 : <CFString 0x1101978 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "NSStoreType"} = <CFString 0x1101988 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "SQLite"}
    9 : <CFString 0x6bba9e0 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "_NSAutoVacuumLevel"} = <CFString 0x6bbb000 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "2"}
    10 : <CFString 0x6bbaef0 [0x1748b48]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion"} = <CFNumber 0x6d84b60 [0x1748b48]>{value = +3, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}
, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}, {
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 386;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            AllFamille = <5a5b78eb 9edf4005 bbe8a8d5 e85fd102 3c6d4040 f1b7fc6c 208bdf48 b8b44695>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "45640157-116E-4616-93C5-2DA6027F4E9C";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
}
```

Comment: Make sure to Delete App from Simulator every time you make any change to Model..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's maybe because you added that attribute. So your new database is not consistent with your old one. Try delete the database under simulator's folder and run again.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is happening because the Managed Object Model used to save your database was different, since you've added new a new entity your modified Managed Object Model cannot be used to load data saved with the former model.

You can delete the app from simulator/device if you are working on the first version of your database. But if you are changing an already published app this can turn into an huge issue, because you cannot ask your users to uninstall your app before installing a new version.

In this case you should create a new version of your Managed Object Model and then configure Core Data to perform a Lightweight Migration on your database from your previous model version to the newest.

Please follow [the steps detailed in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html).